# Insert in 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to INSERT certain items ORDER BY monster names,

For example there is an monster called 'SPIDER' this monster has certain items for example: 'bones, legs, more items' the drops of SPIDER are all in 'log_mitem'.

So my problem is when I hit SUBMIT I want just to create a 'log_create' which creates with success, but in the table 'log_drops' I need to INSERT all items of monster spider for E.X. as you see I've used $items and $dropslq for this one but it doesn't work.

```
$name = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']));
$id = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['id']));
$name2 = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $name);
$game = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['game']));
$info = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['info'])); 
$mobname = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['mobname']));
$sql = "INSERT INTO log_create(`name`, name2, game, monster, info)VALUES('$name', '$name2', '$game', '$mobname', '$info')";
$drop = "SELECT itemname FROM log_mitem ON mobname = '".$mobname."'";
if($dropres = $db->query($drop))
    $items = $dropres->itemname;
$dropslq = "INSERT INTO log_drops(item, mobname, game, log_id, log_name)VALUES('$items', '$mobname', '$game', '$id', '$name')";
```

Comment: What's in `$items`? What does your `->query()` return?

Comment: where your `insert` calls?

Comment: I've changed `$dropres = $db->query($drop))` to `$dropres = $drop->fetch_object())` I got this  error ` Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in `

Comment: ... why change? you must to use both!

Comment: @vp_arth Still cannot take the item information, he left its blanc

Comment: I still get a FATAL ERROR message when i use this: ` $dropres = $db->query($drop);
 $dropres2 = $dropres->fetch_object();`  error: `atal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in`

Answer (score 0):

Use serialize and unserialize functions http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to insert multiple items, you need to do so in a multi-insert clause or a loop. Otherwise, you could serialize your items array into delimited values (assuming that the item name doesn't include that delimiter), and use implode()/explode() in php to serialize or deseralize. You also could look into using PHP's serialize()/deseralize() functions as well.